# random numbers for 10 textView boxes with a button in android app

Tags: java, android

The layout have 10 "?" ,1 start button and a cancel button. how to make the each "?" to generate a random number between 1 to 100 when press the start button each time, and clear 10 random numbers when press the cancel button at the end. Thankyou so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add your 10 TextViews into a Array.In your Button `onClick`  do a loop `for` from the start to end of the array, each loop generate a random number then set it into textView. same as your Cancel button